# Regex Pattern Not working in c# but working in online regex testers

Tags: c#, regex

In a string like

```
[\\\x2286400000\\\x22,\\\x22604800000\\\x22,2.0]\\n,null,1]\\n\x22,\x22mnr_crd\x22:\x221\x22,\x22msg_dsc\x22:\x22From your Internet address\x22,\x22msg_dvl\x22:\x22Reported by this computer\x22,\x22msg_err\x22:\x22Location unavailable\x22,\x22msg_gps\x22:\x22Using GPS\x22,\x22msg_unk\x22:\x22Unknown\x22,\x22msg_upd\x22:\x22Update location\x22,\x22msg_use\x22:\x22Use precise location\x22,\x22uul_text\x22:\x22Home Location\x22}
```

I am trying to match `Home location` with the regex like

```
(?<=:\\x22Use precise location\\x22,\\x22uul_text\\x22:\\x22)(.+?)(?=\\x22})
```

Here is the whole code:

```
string locationRegExpression = "(?<=:\\x22Use precise location\\x22,\\x22uul_text\\x22:\\x22)(.+?)(?=\\x22})";
Regex locationMmatch = new Regex(locationRegExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection locationCollection = Regex.Matches(locationHtmlContent,locationRegExpression);
// lblCurrentLocation.Text = "Location: " + locationCollection[0];
MessageBox.Show(locationCollection[0].ToString());
```

The above regex code is working fine with the below html code in online regex tester sites but if I use the same regex in C# win forms. Its giving 0 results. Any idea?

[Whole text](https://pastebin.com/iqYFzGLH) here.

Comment: Use a verbatim string literal to define the regex, `@""`. Then use `locationMmatch.Matches(locationHtmlContent)` since `locationMmatch` is a `Regex` object.

Comment: perfect! working now. I dont understand how I missed it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to match a single substring in a string containing literal `\x22` substrings. You need to make sure you match a literal `\` symbol, that is, you need to use two literal backslashes in your pattern. It is better done with a verbatim string literal (to avoid overescaping, use `@"..."`) and it is enough to use a `Regex.Match` method:

```
string locationRegExpression = @"(?<=:\\x22Use precise location\\x22,\\x22uul_text\\x22:\\x22)(.+?)(?=\\x22})";
Regex locationMmatch = new Regex(locationRegExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match locationMatch = locationMmatch.Match(locationHtmlContent);
if (locationMatch.Success) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(locationMatch.Value);
}
```

Note that it might probably be "simpler" to use a capturing group here rather than a combination of lookbehind and lookahead:

```
@":\\x22Use precise location\\x22,\\x22uul_text\\x22:\\x22(.+?)\\x22}"
```

and then

```
MessageBox.Show(locationMatch.Groups[1].Value)
```